# Can't access samba shares from one computer

Tags: samba, file-sharing, smb

I'm running into a problem connecting to my samba share from a single Linux computer. I am able to access the shares using other Linux and Windows computers, but this one won't work, either via autofs or smbclient.

Executing `smbclient -L 10.0.0.12` immediately gives me a response of `do_connect: Connection to 10.0.0.12 failed (Error NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED)` [edit] without even prompting me for credentials[/edit].

Executing `smbclient -L 10.0.0.10` to connect to a different samba server [edit] prompts me for credentials and, after logging in, [/edit] lists the available shares.

I can ping both samba servers from the problem computer.

Aside from the shares themselves, both samba servers have identical configurations. [edit] The samba configuration files are a copy/paste of each other with the only differences being the directories being shared. The permissions on these directories and all configured users are identical as well. [/edit]

I'm at a loss for what could be preventing this one computer from connecting and am hoping someone can help be figure out what's going on.

Thanks!

Comment: "Aside from the shares themselves, both samba servers have identical configurations." Then it practically has to be something in the config for the shares. `valid users` ? `invalid users`? Is the user logged in to the non-working pc a valid user of the share?

Comment: By "aside from the shares" meant that different directories are being shared, otherwise the samba configs are the same including users and the permissions on the shared directories. When attempting to connect to the samba server I can't access from this computer, it never even prompts for credentials. Any other computer I have tried prompts for credentials and upon login, I have access. It's almost like the connection between this computer and this samba server is being blocked somehow.

Comment: Difficult to say any more without poring through the config files.